# when to use Command Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use Immediate windows in Visual studio a lot but I am not sure what are the uses cases for using Command windows. Can it be used for debugging anyting particular? Wondering any other people use it and if so, what exactly they find it useful for?

Comment: I used it to type "immed" when my immediate window goes poof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful for typing in commands to the IDE. You can use it to invoke any command, even ones that are not available on a menu or toolbar.

Comment: any particular one that you use more often?